# MongoDB 3.0 and mongoDB 2.2

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I create NodeJS V8 app and use mongoDB local server.

I had mongoDB version ^2.2.34 and connect to DB

```
    let mongodb = require('mongodb');
    let mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

    let connection = mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Test');

    let getCollection = function (c) {
        return connection.then(function (db) {
            return db.collection(c);
        });
    };
```

It worked. I update my mongoDB version to ^3.0.1 and have error

```
(node:16320) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: db.collection is not a function
```

Why in new version it isn't work and how I can change code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting `connect()` to still return a `db`.  [Read the Mongo upgrade guide](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/upgrade-migration/main/) (emphasis mine):

> What’s new in 3.0
>
> - Support added for Retryable Writes
> - Support added for DNS Seedlists
> - Support added for Change Streams
> - Support added for sessions
> - **`MongoClient.connect` now returns a Client instead of a DB.**
>
> [Full 3.0 Changes Here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/3.0.0/CHANGES_3.0.0.md)

---

With that in mind, your code would look something like this:

```
const {
    MongoClient
} = require("mongodb");

const connection = MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017");

function getCollection(c) {
    return connection
        .then(client => client.db("Test"))
        .then(db => db.collection(c));
}
```